# align View to bottom right in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, responsive-design, responsive

I am making a todo app and I need to add the add to do button to the bottom right of the screen
the method I tried was to use bottom, top, right, and left
problem:
but it was not responsive

Is there any why I can make the is button align to the bottom right of the screen on any screen size

my styles code

```
  FloatingContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
  Floating: {
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray",
    width: 60,
    borderRadius: 100,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    fontSize: 40,
    justifyContent: 'space-between'
  },
```

my button code

```
      <View>
        {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" /> : showToDoList()}
        <View style={MyStyles.FloatingContainer}>
          <Text
            style={MyStyles.Floating}
            onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}
          >
            +
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

[image]

how can I fix this and align my add to do button to the bottom right

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: "absolute"` on the container to position it at the bottom right of the screen. From personal experience I'd recommend to leave the `Text` just for text and move the `onClick` to the container.

```js
FloatingContainer: {
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: 16,
  right: 16,
  height: 60,
  width: 60,
  justifyContent: "space-between",
  borderRadius: 30,
  borderColor: "gray",
  backgroundColor: "white",
  borderWidth: 1,
},
Floating: {
  // just for styling the Text
  fontSize: 40,
},
```

Comment: that made it go a little higher and went to the right side but I want it to go to the bottom right it might work on one phone and won't n work on the other I want it responsive that's the problem

Comment: Yes for it to align to the bottom the parent has to be the whole height of the screen. `flex: 1` should be applied there @RUBAINSTUBE